# How to make icons invisible on wx.ListCtrl in report mode?

Tags: wxpython

I have to get a list with just two string columns. On GTK everything is ok, but on windows 7 I get this:
[image: Windows 7]

```
class ListViewCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)

class ListView(wx.Panel, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS)

        self.il = wx.ImageList(16, 16)        
        self.up = self.il.Add(resources.filter_up.GetBitmap())
        self.dn = self.il.Add(resources.filter_down.GetBitmap())
        self.list = ListViewCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER | wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS | wx.LC_SORT_ASCENDING)
        self.list.SetImageList(self.il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)

        i = 0
        _program_dir = os.path.split(__file__)[0] 
        self.itemDataMap = {}
        for fn in os.listdir(os.path.join(_program_dir, '../design/caps')):            
            self.itemDataMap[i] = (fn, "Line {0}".format(i+1))
            i += 1            
        self.PopulateList()

        listmix.ColumnSorterMixin.__init__(self, 3)
        self.__DoLayout()

    def __DoLayout(self):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        sizer.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)        
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)

    def PopulateList(self):
        info = wx.ListItem()
        info.m_mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT
        info.m_image = -1
        info.m_format = 0
        info.m_text = "File name"
        self.list.InsertColumnInfo(0, info)
        info.m_text = "Column 2"
        self.list.InsertColumnInfo(1, info) 
        for k, v in self.itemDataMap.items():
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, v[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, v[1])
            self.list.SetItemData(index, k)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, 100)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(1, wx.LIST_AUTOSIZE)        
        self.currentItem = 0

    def GetListCtrl(self):
        return self.list

    def GetSortImages(self):
        return (self.dn, self.up)
```

Every line use the image number 0 from the attached image list. How can I get rid of this icons?

*wxPython 2.9.2.4, Win7 x64*

**UPDATE:**

Here is a list from GTK (no icons as you see):

[image: GTK]

Comment: Could you please show us what things look like on GTK, where it works?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it right now, at least in 6 hours...

Comment: Please, see how it looks like in GTK.

Comment: I have to check it on OSX as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft ListView widget has a wonderful "feature"  where if there is an image list assigned to the control then it assumes that you always want to display an image for every item.  If you don't specify one for an item then it will use the first one in the image list for you, because according to MS that is what you really wanted to do but just forgot to do it yourself.  Apparently.

Anyway, the workaround is to either make the first image in the image list be a fully transparent icon, or to explicitly assign some other icon to the items.

Comment: A side effect of crossplatform programming))) Thank you!